# Mirror Third Party Web Services Internally

Tags: java, api, web-services, scraping, intranet

When using third party web services one often runs into problems where the usage of the service over the network causes performance issues, usage is limited and web service structural changes influence stability and force unplanned changes.

It would be great if there were an API (preferably Java-based) that could persist a list of URL's & parameters and create a clone of the third party web services for hosting internally so that usage is unlimited, doesn't have the same performance issues and can be audited/versioned so that in the event of structural changes a rollback can be performed.

It obviously seems like a simple matter of HTML scraping at first but it's really more advanced where management features are available and also reliable mirroring. For **example**, if a web service responds with elements that contain a dynamic URLs to other web services - then these may or may not need to be persisted recursively.

Comment: You want a [proxy server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse)

Comment: Would a proxy server cater to inbound anchors within web service response xml?